# asp.net core live mp4 streaming

Tags: asp.net-core, video, ffmpeg, streaming, mp4

Prologue:

I have a hikvision ipcamera that streams raw h264 from a rtsp:// url, I need to play this live feed in the browser.

I managed to get a basic RTSP->ffmpeg-> (faststart) mp4 pipeline working and I can play the video when saved to a file.

I don't understand how to make my controller action "streamable".

I've tried various approaches like writing to Response.Body, Transfer-Encoding: chunked but nothing seems to work.
Here is the basic code:

```
public IActionResult Play5(){    
      var ms = new MemoryStream();
      var muxer = new RTSPToMp4(ms);
      Task.Run(() => muxer.Stream());
      return new FileStreamResult(ms, "video/mp4");
}
```

The memory stream contains the live feed but the response is empty here is the request\response from chrome:

Request

```
method: GET
:path: /api/stream/play5
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
accept-language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cache-control: no-cache
pragma: no-cache
range: bytes=0-
referer: https://localhost:5001/Stream
sec-fetch-dest: video
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36
```

Response

```
content-length: 0
content-type: video/mp4
date: Thu, 08 Oct 2020 14:31:06 GMT
server: Kestrel
status: 200
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

MP4 cannot be live streamed.

Fastest solution is that you should keep the H.264 format as is (not contained inside some MP4 file) and just use any [JavaScript based H.264 decoder](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=js+h264+player).